# How do I modify series values for charts in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, series

So if I have the numbers 1 through 5 in cells A1 through A5,
 when I select series values for a chart in Excel, how do I plot A1:A5 as -1 through -5?

How can I modify:
='All Data'!$A$1:$A$5
without creating cells on my spreadsheet?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.  You have plotted values, but those aren't the values you want?

Answer (score 0):

Put a hyphen in A1 before `1`, copy A1, select A2:A5 Paste Special, Values with Operation Multiply.

Answer (score 0):

"How can I modify [the input data] without creating cells on my spreadsheet?"

Excel plots worksheet data. It sounds like A1:A5 contains your Y values and you want X values of -1 to -5. The most efficient way to do this is to put these values into a worksheet range, and using the Edit Data dialog, set this range as your X values.

You can use an array of values, which seems great but is harder to maintain, and you are limited to how large an array you can use.

If you plot your Y values, you get a series formula like this (select the chart series and look at the formula bar):

=SERIES(,,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,1)

There are no entries for series name, so Excel just calls it Series1, nor for X values, so Excel uses 1,2,3,4,5.

Edit the series formula to this:

=SERIES(,{-1,-2,-3,-4,-5},Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,1)

Note: If you make an XY Scatter chart, this array will be used as numerical X values, and by default -5 will be furthest left.

If you make a line chart, the line will be unchanged, but the array entries will be used as text (non-numeric) labels in the left-to-right order in which they appear in the array.